# Modulus Function to Avoid Integer Overflow in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, sum, modulus, integer-overflow

If I have 2 `int` or `long long` variables, call them `a` and `b`, and I want to compute the sum `(a + b) mod p`, where p is a large prime integer, how can I utilize the modulo operator in C++ to achieve the desired result?

I have tried `(a + b) % p`, but this gives overflow sometimes, since `a + b` will overflow before the mod is applied.

Other similar approaches I have tried seem to avoid overflow, but give an incorrect result.

How can I use the modulo operator in this case to correctly compute the desired sum, while avoiding overflow?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
a %= p
b %= p
c = p-a

if(b==c)
  sum = 0
if (b<c)
 sum = a+b
if (b>c)
 sum = b-c
```

**EDIT:** The trick is to avoid any calculation that might cause overflow, *without knowing where the limit is.* All we know is that the given a, b and p are below the limit -- maybe *just* below the limit.

After the first two steps (`a%=p;b%=p;`) we know `a<p` and `b<p`. We still daren't add `a+b`, because that sum might exceed p and break the limit<sup>*</sup>. But we can see how much room we have left with `c = p-a`, which is safe because we know that `c<=p` and `c>0`. (The stated types are unsigned, but we may as well avoid negative numbers, if only because their limits are sometimes off by one from the negatives of the *positive* limits, in ways I can never remember.)

If b=c, then b=p-a, so a+b=p, so the sum (mod p) is zero.

If `b<c`, then `a+b<p`, so we can safely compute `a+b` (and need not apply the modulo).

if `b>c`, then it is *not* safe to compute `a+b`, but we know that the number we're looking for is `a+b-p`, which we can rewrite as `b-(p-a)`, and we already have `b` and `p-a`, so we can safely perform that subtraction.

(*) <sub>That's right, I said "daren't". It's a perfectly good word.</sub>

Comment: Nice. Perhaps an explanation of why this works would be helpful as well.

Comment: @M.M: Offhand, I'm not sure, since I'm not sure how modulo is defined for negative numbers.

Comment: It's defined so that (for positive x) `(-x) % y` gives `-(x%y)`